# real time bootstrap drop-down issue in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tired one of the real time application [dropdown bootstrap] in mega menu but its highlighting the path as well as getting the string name but if i use a click option, i am could not able to click in mega menu option

```
driver.get("https://www.online.citibank.co.in/");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement loan=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='mainNavList visible-desktop']//li//a[@title='Loans']"));
loan.click();
String name=loan.getAttribute("innerHTML");

System.out.println(" menu name is " +name);
```

o/p:- Loans

can any one tell me the issue

Comment: I think your `loan.click();` works perfect & `System.out.println(" menu name is " +name);` prints **Loans**, so what is your exact question?

Comment: ones i clicked the loan by using loan.click(); drop down is not coming !!! that's an issue

Comment: I notice the page is very slowly when i open it on my chrome browser.  if  it's same on your side,  try adding  sleep() for 50 seconds before findElement(). if script can work well with sleep(),  means you need to add explicit wait:  WebDriverWait.until()

Comment: Hi @yong i tried by using Thread.sleep(50); but still the issue persist :(

Comment: Hi Shiva, for 50  seconds, should be Thread.sleep(50*1000), did you as that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact solution but in this way, you can select drop down menu.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    action.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    action.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    action.perform();
```

Comment: yeah @zsbappa but i am trying to do this action in mega menu, i think action is not required

Comment: instead of perform you can do any expected operation

Comment: Thank you @zsbappa ll try it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but still u facing problem the use explicit wait for that. Please try this code:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.online.citibank.co.in/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement loan=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='mainNavList visible-desktop']//li//a[@title='Loans']"));
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(loan));
loan.click();
String name=loan.getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.println(" menu name is " +name);
```